# How to use async await while retaining the original data order output since the order is based on the awaiting time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to use async to simulate passing a request to a website and wait the website return the result, and print out the result in original order instead of the "after async await" order.

```
import asyncio
import random

class Count: #Assume data only hold the data ID number
  count = 0

def output(count):
  print(count) #Assume storing the ID and content of the website into a database

async def count():
  while True:
    Count.count = Count.count + 1 #Update the data reference ID by increasing one
    count = Count.count #Assume ID is the variable that will be pass to a website
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 10)) #Simluate connect to the website and passing the ID variables and return the result from the website
    output(count)
    if Count.count>9:
      break

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(count(), count(),count(),count())
if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
3
1
5
4
2
6
8
7
10
9
```

However, this is not the result I wanted, although the processing speed is increased using asyn/await but I have to sacrifice the order of the data. Is there any way that I could still use async to speed up the process while retaining the original ID number order of the data? Of course, I can save all the data, and sort the data ID in ascending order, but is there any smarter wait to do it such that the second async count() function will only call the output() function right after the first async count() function has called the output() function?

Intended Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: you could sort your data after all the async calls return, i don't think there's a way to control which one returns first without something overly complicated

Comment: the input sample is not representative: note that `Count.count` can be incremented by multiple coroutines in same time. Post a scheme that is more close to your real case.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for pointing out, I can simply lock it and release it right?